# Ubuntu won't detect second monitor on HDMI

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

So, as the title says, my Ubuntu doesn't detect my second monitor on the HDMI port of my laptop. I know it's not a hardware problem, since it does work perfectly on my Windows (dual boot).
It did work when I first installed Ubuntu 18.04, but after updating my kernel this issue popped up.

I have searched for possible solutions, but none I've come across so far seem to fix it.

I'm using an Nvidia GTX 1060, these are the outputs of

`xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93
(Plus a whole bunch of other resolutions)
```

`sudo lshw -c display`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    version: a1
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
*-display
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 00
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
    resources: irq:137 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`uname -r`:

```
4.19.0-041900-generic
```

Any help? If you need more info, just tell me which command I need to execute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of   `uname -r`, seems to be a kernel issue. Try to use an older kernel by selecting it at the grub menu. Did you try `xrandr --auto`.

Comment: Thanks!
I added the output in the original post. `xrandr --auto` doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Update: it works now! I deleted all the Nvidia files, added the ppa repos and installed a later version of the drivers in tty.

Comment: @WoutV Hi, I have similar problem, could you please describe, what ppa repos have you installed to make this work? Thanks!